# Finding nil in systemDouble value in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, null, swift4

I'm trying to find the current system version in Swift 4, I have a label that I will set to either "Updated" or "Not Updated", depending on whether the current iOS version is >= 11.2 or < 11.2.

This works in the emulator just fine, but when I run it on my iPhone X, it returns an error saying: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", stating that systemDouble is equal to nil.

I've tried saying if systemDouble != nil and  if systemDouble == nil, but nothing seems to be working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Code below:

```
@IBOutlet weak var updateStatus: UILabel!


let systemVersion = UIDevice.current.systemVersion
let systemDouble = Double(systemVersion)



if (updateStatus  != nil && systemDouble! >= 11.2)

{
    updateStatus.text! = "Updated"
    updateStatus.textColor = UIColor.green
}

else if (updateStatus != nil && systemDouble! < 11.2)
{
    updateStatus.text! = "Not Updated" + String (systemVersion)
    updateStatus.textColor = UIColor.red

}
```

Comment: `UIDevice.current.systemVersion`  returns a `String`. If the OS is something like `"10.0.1"` it will return `nil`

Comment: I would suggest using `ProcessInfo().operatingSystemVersion.majorVersion` instead. You can also check `minorVersion` and `patchVersion`

Comment: @LeoDabus Worked like a charm! minorVersion and patchVersion seem to return 2.0, and 6.0 respectively for some reason, but majorVersion returns 11 which is what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`systemVersion` is a string, and there's no guarantee that it can be converted to a number. So when you force unwrap it, you get an error.

I would suggest using `if #available(iOS 11.2, *)` instead.